# Problem using apt in Kali Linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux and every time I use `apt-get update` or any command with `apt` in terminal I receive this message:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Please post content of this file: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list`

Comment: Kali ask not to change the sources.list. You shouldn't try try to have a different source.list . Most likely people won't help you with Kali Linux : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: @Kiwy thanks for help , for that link it helps me to re-think about when to use Kali

Comment: @yahol thanks i checked it an will see the standard source list on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `atom.list` repository definition is broken... To restore your ability to run `apt`, move it out of the way:

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.{list,broken}
```

If you don’t plan on fixing it, you can delete it instead:

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list
```

As others have mentioned, Kali isn’t really appropriate for beginners; you might do better with another distribution first. See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/86440) for details.